# SQL Connection Error While Connecting to Local Instance Using SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to connect local instance in my SSMS 2005. it is showing me this error.. while i can connect the my system instance remotely or using Code. Last time it was working 2 days ago. now how suddenly this can happen.

[image]

Comment: Is your machine on a domain? If so, are you currently connected to the domain?

Comment: yes.. its a domain system and i am already connected to domain. i tried using windows authentication also it is showing me same error

Comment: In that case, check the user's password. That error sometimes means that the user's password has expired and needs changing. What happens if you try to log on to a machine as that user?

Comment: I tried to login with all user available for the local instance. but for all showing same error. and if the password is expired then how i am able to connect using Code C# and also remotely

Answer (score 0):

In the Sql Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (or the name of your instance) check if TCP/IP Protocol is Enabled. If not, set to...

[SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJWNH.png)

Comment: Thanks.. but its already enabled. though i tried again restarting the service but nothing helped.

Comment: The above support link is related to remote server. but for me its the local instance. and i have read the article. it no use of me

Comment: I understand.
In this link have some solutions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2015/07/09/an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-amp-dbnetlib-connectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-when-connecting-to-sql-server.aspx

They are the same settings as suggested above, but these are the windows registry.
Changing the registry can work. I've seen bugs where SQL settings need to be performed directly in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution above isn´t work. I suggest you uninstall and reinstall SQL Server native client on the local computer